# Efficiently get diff of large data set?

Tags: php, mysql, diff, large-data

I need to be able to diff the results of two queries, showing the rows that are in the "old" set but aren't in the "new"... and then showing the rows that are in the "new" set but not the old.

Right now, i'm pulling the results into an array, and then doing an array_diff(). But, i'm hitting some resource and timing issues, as the sets are close to 1 million rows each.

The schema is the same in both result sets (barring the setId number and the table's autoincrement number), so i assume there's a good way to do it directly in MySQL... but im not finding how.

```
Example Table Schema:
rowId,setId,userId,name

Example Data:
    1,1,user1,John
    2,1,user2,Sally
    3,1,user3,Tom
    4,2,user1,John
    5,2,user2,Thomas
    6,2,user4,Frank
```

What i'm needing to do, is figure out the adds/deletes between setId 1 and setId 2.

So, the result of the diff should (for the example) show:

```
Rows that are in both setId1 and setId2
    1,1,user1,John

Rows that are in setId 1 but not in setId2
    2,1,user2,Sally
    3,1,user3,Tom

Rows that are in setId 2 but not in setId1
    5,2,user2,Thomas
    6,2,user4,Frank
```

I think that's all the details. And i think i got the example correct. Any help would be appreciated. Solutions in MySQL or PHP are fine by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing, was adding a checksum column to the necessary tables being diffed. That way, instead of having to select multiple columns for comparison, the diff could be done against a single column (the checksum value).

The checksum value was a simple md5 hash of a serialized array that contained the columns to be diffed. So... it was like this in PHP:

```
$checksumString = serialize($arrayOfColumnValues);
$checksumValue = md5($checksumString);
```

That $checksumValue would then be inserted/updated into the tables, and then we can more easily do the joins/unions etc on a single column to find the differences. It ended up looking something like this:

```
SELECT  i.id, i.checksumvalue
FROM    SAMPLE_TABLE_I i
WHERE   i.checksumvalue not in(select checksumvalue from SAMPLE_TABLE_II)
UNION ALL
SELECT  ii.id, ii.checksumvalue
FROM    SAMPLE_TABLE_II ii
WHERE   ii.checksumvalue not in(select checksumvalue from SAMPLE_TABLE_I);
```

This runs fast enough for my purposes, at least for now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` or `not exists` to get rows that are in both or only 1 set.

Users in set 1 but not set 2 (just flip tables for the opposite):

```
select * from set1 s1
where set_id = 1
and not exists (
  select count(*) from set1 s2
  where s1.user1 = s2.user1
)
```

Users that are in both sets

```
select * from set2 s2
where set_id = 2  
and exists (
    select 1 from set1 s1
    where s1.setId = 1
    and s2.user1 = s1.user1
)
```

If you only want distinct users in both groups then `group by user1`:

```
select min(rowId), user1 from set1
where set_id in (1,2)
group by user1
having count(distinct set_id) = 2
```

or for users in group but not the other

```
select min(rowId), user1 from set1
where set_id in (1,2)
group by user1
having count(case when set_id <> 1 then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Going to give this a shot this weekend. Thanks for the quick reply.